# SwiftUI: Popover or dismiss viewcontroller

Tags: swiftui

I am studying SwiftUI and I write this to show new view.

```
NavigationButton(destination: LanguagePage()) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("Hello World")
                            }
                        }
```

In that LanguagePage, how can I go back to previous page when user tap on button (like dismissviewcontroller or popviewcontroller)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There are no manual navigation stack management features in SwiftUI as of Xcode 11 beta 2.

Comment: For a survey of what you can do so far, see https://medium.com/@michaellong/swiftui-deep-inside-navigationview-4d25d57a236c

Answer (score 2):

instead of NavigationButton use Navigation DestinationLink

but You should import Combine

```
struct AView: View {
var link: NavigationDestinationLink<BView>
var publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

init() {
let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
self.link = NavigationDestinationLink(
    BView(onDismiss: { publisher.send() }),
    isDetail: false
)
self.publisher = publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var body: some View {
NavigationView {
    Button(action:{
    self.link.presented?.value = true


 }) {
        Text("Go to B")
    }.onReceive(publisher, perform: { _ in
        self.link.presented?.value = false
    })
}
}
}

struct BView: View {
var onDismiss: () -> Void
var body: some View {
Button(action: self.onDismiss) {
    Text("Come back to A")
}
}
}
```